# passing portion of json string values to jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have following json string. I need only 'locked' item and need to pass to a jquery function.I used json encode from php to get the string.

```
{"ignored":[],"status":{"message":"success","code":200},"locked":[8089033,809241‌​5]}
```

My jquery function is as follows

```
$.map(locked, function (id) {
    $("#grid-table tr#" + id)
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .after($("<img src='http://www.placehold.it/20x10/ff0000'>"));
    });
});
```

I am not getting an idea how to get only locked= [8089033,809241‌​5];  to my jquery function

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have a valid Json string using a validator like this [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

To get only locked you can parse the Json like this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"ignored":[],"status":{"message":"success","code":200},"locked":[8089033,809241‌​5]}' );
```

Then you can get the Locked object like this

```
obj.locked
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out jsonlint. I do not understand the error jsonlint is referring to. It seems to be a proper array. Can you please explain?

Comment: looks like there was a hidden char in the last element in the array (not sure which one). So just clean it by removing the last element completely and retyping it.. try this string: '{
    "ignored": [],
    "status": {
        "message": "success",
        "code": 200
    },
    "locked": [
        8089033,
        8092415
    ]
}' it works fine, weird ha!

Comment: I am getting an unexpected character in json String

Comment: Did you checkout my above comment. It works fine for me. To help you mode I made a codepen. check it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yAwLi)